# consultas en mongodb independiente de si existe o no una variable

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

¿Como hacer una búsqueda de un documento, dependiendo de una variable si existe o no?

He intentado hacer una búsqueda

```
var language = req.body.language
Teacher.find({'language':language})
```

Lo que quiero saber, es como puedo hacer una búsqueda, tanto si existe si existe el idioma o no.

Si no existe el idioma, me buscará todos los profesores, 
y si existe un idioma en concreto me buscará solo los de ese idioma

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ir creando los parámetros de la query gradualmente, es decir, comprobar si el parámetro existe pues lo añades al objeto `query`. Sino no hay ningún parámetro te devolverá todo los registros porque `query` no contiene ningún parámetro.

```
const query = {}
var language = req.body.language

if (language) {
  query.language = language
}

Teacher.find(query)
```

Comment: y si fuese un subdocumento? `hour: [{ hour_time:String, pricea:Number,priceb:Number,   }],`

Comment: mirate esto https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

Comment: si fuese un array tendrías que usar $elemMatch: query.hour = {$elemMatch: {pricea: 4}}